# Dynamic array with variable sized columns

Tags: visual-c++, dynamic, ifstream

I am reading a file which has variable sized columns:

0 1 3 0

0 2 0

0 4 0

My code reads the file, but after the last "0" it outputs two numbers which are   garbage. Output is: 0130020040-8457888-85648454 (something like that): Please Help me THANK YOU

```
int **routes  = new int *[3]; //create route matrix

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{   
    routes[i] = new int[sizeof(routes)];
}


    ifstream routefile;
    routefile.open("Sweep_routes.txt");

    if(routefile.fail()){
        cout << "ERROR";
        exit(1);}
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<sizeof(routes);j++){
            routefile>>routes[i][j]; //read
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<sizeof(routes);j++){
            cout << routes[i][j]; //display
        }
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(routes)` does't give you the number of items in an array, it gives you the number of bytes in a pointer. I think this is the basis of your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you have any suggestions on how I can correct this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this alternative to your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<std::string, 3>, 3> routes;
    std::ifstream routefile("Sweep_routes.txt");

    if (routefile)
    {
        for (auto x : routes)
        {
            for (auto y : x)
            {
                if (routefile >> y)
                    std::cout << y;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```